# Geopandas .difference between two different shapes produces empty difference

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I have been puzzled by this, and I feel like it's a geopandas bug.

```
base = gpd.GeoSeries(dist_to_remove).plot(edgecolor='black', color='yellow')
gpd.GeoSeries(prec_shape).plot(ax = base, color='red', edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

So this should be an easy difference to compute. However, upon doing

```
dist_to_remove.difference(prec_shape)
```

[image]

I get the above (there is a tiny tiny square in the lower left). The area has shrunk by an enormous magnitude. I am really confused as to what is happening. The odd part is, if I change the buffer on prec_shape, the difference occurs as expected. I'm really confused as to what's going on right now, is this a shapely/geopandas bug?